# Unable to update Ubuntu 18.04 with the error: The repository is no longer signed

Tags: 18.04, updates

I am using Ubuntu 18.04. When I tried to update with `sudo apt update` I got the following errors:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/susan-spencer/seamly2d/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/susan-spencer/seamly2d/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can anyone provide instructions for how to fix this? I would appreciate step-by-step instructions.

Comment: That PPA no longer exists. Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

The `seamly2d` package no longer exists in the PPA from `susan-spencer`.  It will need to be removed.

We have a highly active question about removing PPAs: [How can PPAs be removed?](https://askubuntu.com/q/307/) Answers to this question include step-by-step instructions for removing a PPA.

You may also want to read: [Are PPAs safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/q/35629). **PPAs are not official Ubuntu software**.  Anyone can make a PPA to distribute software. Some PPAs can break your system, especially if they are outdated, obscure, and/or poorly maintained.

Also note that `sudo apt update` only updates the list of available software. While this command is supposed to be run before doing anything else in `apt`, you should also run `sudo apt upgrade` after `sudo apt update` if you want to actually perform updates to your installed software.